# Sorry, you don't have access to this page MySite in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, mysite

I configured MySite in SharePoint 2013, when I am clicking on Newsfeed I am able to see the about me and People.

After few sec, I am getting   `"Sorry, you don't have access to this page"` this message I am getting once my site collection is created I can able to see in Viewallsitecolections in central admin.Can anyone please help why I am getting this problem.

I configured correctly like self-service creation and also permission policy to everyone for creating subsites.

Comment: Have you double checked the permission levels and settings for the page/site so that you certainly have permission to access it? :-)

Comment: where i have to give the permissions

Comment: I'm not sure because I have no Sharepoint Server configuration as we have Sharepoint Online. But I would guess you can check the permission levels and settings somewhere in central admin center. You might find some helpful information in here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362(v=office.15).aspx :)

Comment: I tried all the same things...but still same issue..

Comment: Ok sorry that I couldn't help you.. If I find out any solutions, I'll let you know! :-)